# MacVim behaving strangely with my aliases (even setting shell=/bin/bash\ -l)

Tags: bash, vim, alias, macvim, .bash-profile

I wanted to write some scripts and have MacVim call some bash commands. I have some aliases and wanted vim to be able to call them, so I knew I needed a login shell, just didn't know how to make vim use one.

I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/vim-is-not-obeying-command-aliases (which didn't work for my MacVim); and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/vim-is-not-obeying-command-aliases which seemed like a good idea.

So I opened my .vimrc and put this in: `set shell=/bin/bash\ -l`.

Now something very strange is happening: I have an alias in my `.bash_profile`, like so:

```
alias mytest='echo "TEST!!"'
```

My `.bashrc` sources `.bash_profile`, so I know it shouldn't be a matter of where the alias is set. If I go inside vim and run: `:! alias mytest`

I see this:

```
alias mytest='echo "TEST!!"'

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I run `:! mytest`, though, this is what I get:

```
/bin/bash: mytest: command not found

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So I'm all out of ideas about how this can be happening. How come when I run "alias" the alias is there, but when I run the alias itself, bash doesn't recognize it?

I appreciate any insight anyone can give me on this matter.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I now tried changing my `.vimrc` line to:

```
set shell=/bin/bash\ -li
```

In order to make the shell interactive as well as being a login shell, and it worked.

So I change my question a bit: Why does this make sense? As I understand it, a login shell runs my `.bash_profile`, and thus loads my aliases. Why is it not sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are intended as user shorthand, so they only really make sense in interactive shells. Therefore, as the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says: "Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below)."  I suppose you could add `shopt -s expand_aliases` to your .bash_profile, but that might cause unexpected behavior in other sorts of non-interactive shells...

Comment: Damn, had not gotten to that part of the bash man page. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `:! bash -ic 'mytest; exit'`